# Is there any cross browser way to get width of a DIV with scrollbars(if present)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$('#div').width()` returns the width of div without scrollbars. Is there any jquery or any other cross-browser solution that can return width of div with scrollbar? `

Answer (score 1):

yes it is,

check

```
$('#div').outerWidth(true)
```

http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/